# How to average every two rows of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame (with 1000's of columns):

```
df<- structure(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2), 
              .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
               c("t1", "t2", "t3")))
```

What would be an efficient way to get average of every two rows?

Result I want:

```
     t1 t2 t3
a    1  2  3
b    2  2  3
a_b  1.5 2 3
c    2  2  2
d    1  1  2
c_d  1.5 1.5 2
```

Comment: The fact that you need this to scale (you mention in comments on answers that there's the possibility of thousands of columns) is good information to add into your question, so folks know what your needs are before helping you figure it out

Comment: Why this format? Can you not keep the means as a separate matrix? Also, why do you keep numbers as characters?

Comment: Your current example is not a dataframe, it is character matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on ever 2 rows, then get mean per column, and rbind, and rbind all again.

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(seq(1, nrow(df), 2), function(i){
          x <- df[ i:(i + 1), , drop = FALSE]
          res <- rbind(x, colSums(x)/2)
          rownames(res)[ nrow(res) ] <- paste(rownames(x), collapse = "_")
          res
        }))

#      t1  t2 t3
# a   1.0 2.0  3
# b   2.0 2.0  3
# a_b 1.5 2.0  3
# c   2.0 2.0  2
# d   1.0 1.0  2
# c_d 1.5 1.5  2
```

Comment: This is the best way to achieve OP's output while for larger dataset it would be time consuming. That is however due to the desired output which is so specific (and bizarre to my eyes). Your answer is a neat one though. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 data.frame() %>%
 rownames_to_column() %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric) %>%
 group_by(group = gl(n()/2, 2)) %>%
 group_map(~ bind_rows(.x, tibble(rowname = paste(.x$rowname, collapse = "_"), 
                                  t1 = mean(.x$t1),
                                  t2 = mean(.x$t2),
                                  t3 = mean(.x$t3)))) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-group)

  rowname    t1    t2    t3
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     2       2
2 b         2     2       2
3 a_b       1.5   2       2
4 c         2     2       1
5 d         1     1       1
6 c_d       1.5   1.5     1
```

The first three rows could be omitted if you create it beforehand as a `data.frame`, with names as a column and with factors as numeric variables. Then, what it does, is to, first, create a grouping variables using `gl()`. Second, it calculates the means, creates the name as a combination of the two elements in the group and binds it with the original data. Finally, it ungroups and removes the redundant variable.

Comment: What if you have 1000s of columns?

Comment: Then, I think, there are better possibilities. Right now, I cannot see a clever possibility for that using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` approach.
**Update**: If you really need the row names (`a`, `b`, `a_b`, etc) see after my original solution for a scalable, but more convoluted, version.

**Original**

```
df <- df %>% as_tibble()
n <- nrow(df)/2
orig <- df %>% mutate(grp = sort(rep(1:2, n)))
means <- orig %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_all(mean)

bind_rows(orig, means) %>% arrange(grp) %>% select(-grp)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     t1    t2    t3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   1     2       3
2   2     2       3
3   1.5   2       3
4   2     2       2
5   1     1       2
6   1.5   1.5     2
```

**Updated with row names**

```
rnames <- row.names(df)
df <- df %>% as_tibble() 

n <- (nrow(df)/2)

orig <- df %>% 
  mutate(grp = sort(rep(1:n, n)), rn = rnames)

means <- orig %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(rn = paste0(rn, collapse="_")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)

bind_rows(orig, means) %>% arrange(grp) %>% select(-grp)
```

Output:

```
     t1    t2    t3 rn   
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1   1     2       3 a    
2   2     2       3 b    
3   1.5   2       3 a_b  
4   2     2       2 c    
5   1     1       2 d    
6   1.5   1.5     2 c_d
```

Comment: Do you need ``rep(1:2, n)`` instead of ``rep(1:n,n)`` for the case with >4 rows? And in original I think you need ``means <- orig`` rather than ``means <- df``.

Answer (score 1):

a `base` R solution that works with any number of columns

```
M <- matrix(unlist(c(df)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
M <- cbind(M, rowMeans(M))
M <- matrix(c(t(M)),ncol = ncol(df), byrow = FALSE)

# add row names and column names 
row.names <- matrix(rownames(df), ncol = 2 ,byrow = TRUE)
rownames(M) <- c(t(cbind(row.names, apply(row.names,1, paste, collapse = "_"))))
colnames(M) <- colnames(df)


#        t1   t2   t3
#  a    1.0  2.0    3
#  b    2.0  2.0    3
#  a_b  1.5  2.0    3
#  c    2.0  2.0    2
#  d    1.0  1.0    2
#  c_d  1.5  1.5    2
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the `dplyr` package.
Note that the data I use is slightly different from the data you are using: in your data the numbers are actually character values.

```
df <- structure(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2), 
               .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                                            c("t1", "t2", "t3")))
```

First I create the summary tibble (which contains the means).

```
    library(dplyr)
    df_summary <- df %>% as_tibble(rownames = "names") %>% 
      group_by(ceiling(1:n() / 2)) %>% 
      summarise(names = paste(names, collapse = "_"),
                t1 = mean(t1),
                t2 = mean(t2),
                t3 = mean(t3)) %>% 
      select(-1)
    # A tibble: 2 x 4
      names    t1    t2    t3
      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 a_b     1.5   2       3
    2 c_d     1.5   1.5     2
```

Then I combine the summary data with original data:

```
 df_summary %>% bind_rows(df %>% as_tibble(rownames = "names")) %>% 
  slice(3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  names    t1    t2    t3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a       1     2       3
2 b       2     2       3
3 a_b     1.5   2       3
4 c       2     2       2
5 d       1     1       2
6 c_d     1.5   1.5     2
```

Comment: What if you have 1000s of columns?

Answer (score 0):

This function averages based on a column named "group"
and should be in the dataset.
x is a data frame or a matrix.

```
rowm = function(x){
x = as.data.frame(x)
u = unique(x$group) 
r = rep(NA, ncol(x)*length(u))
tempDF = matrix(r, ncol=ncol(x))
counter=0
for(i in u){
    counter = counter+1
    tempDF[counter, ] = colMeans(x[x$group==i, ], )
}
colnames(tempDF) = colnames(x)
return(tempDF)}
```