# Merging two rows by taking the mean, combining names and keeping other columns the same – R

Tags: r, merge, row, average, mean

I have a time-series-cross-sectional data frame with circa 400 observations like this:

```
country    year    value
Belgium    2015    3
Belgium    2016    5
Belgium    2017    8
Belgium    2018    10
Malta      2015    1
Malta      2016    3
...        ...     ...
```

But I need a transformed version with two years combined (odd number first) by taking the mean of the values, combining the years and keeping the name of the country the same. Like this:

```
country    year         value(mean)
Belgium    2015_2016    4
Belgium    2017_2018    9
Malta      2015_2016    2
...        ...          ...
```

I've tried all the solution to this question ([How to average every two rows of dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959278/how-to-average-every-two-rows-of-dataframe-in-r)) but I wasn't able to adjust these in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(id = rep(1:n(), length.out = n(), each = 2)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(country    = unique(country),
            year       = paste0(year[1], '_', year[2]),
            value_mean = mean(value))
```

This assumes that you will always have an even number of rows per country and that your data is already sorted by year.

Comment: Hi deschen, this works perfectly. Thank you! I have a plenty more data frames to adjust like this but I'm not sure if the assumption you mentioned are valid for all of those. Do you have an idea for a less well sorted df?

Comment: One more thing: I've tried to upvote your answer but I'm a newbie and stackoverflow doesn't show my vote immediately. but it's counted and will be displayed in the future i think. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, the easiest is that you just sort your data before running this function, e.g. by `df %>% arrange(country, year)`. As for upvoting. I think as a newbie, you can't upvote, but if the solution solves your problem, you could still accept it as an answer so that others can see there's a solution.